# Can I have more than one record with same user info except phone number in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Can I have same username and email in a table but different phone number where phone number is kept in another table with the id of user table.

One more thing if I put same user info record more than record in one table that is user table with different phone number in that table(Not by putting by foreign key concept in another phone number table) so what id the problem.

I am new to database please make me clear my concept.Please help me.

Comment: If a set of columns is a unique key or a primary key, there must be only one row with a specific set of values in these columns. Period.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can have same username and email in a table but different phone number  by making

```
GROUP BY phone_number
```

Do note: That you will be selected more than one row for users who has more than one phone number, which may not be ideal if you are looking for a simple result of users.  So you may want to consider the queries up.